# Having problem while executing the main file

Tags: java, netbeans

I am just a beginner trying to use a git java project, I have downloaded a java project from git and when I try to run the splash.java file it says:-

> Class "Electricity.splash" does not have a main method

**Here's the screenshot of the screen:-**

[Screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e78IF.png)

**conn.java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Hp pc
 */
class conn {
    
}
```

**screenshot of conn.java file in Electricity folder**

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGgmc.png)

**Here's my splash.java which has the main method:**

```
package Electricity;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class splash {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        fframe f1 = new fframe();
        f1.setVisible(true);
        int i;
        int x=1;
        for(i=2; i<=600; i+=4, x+=1){
            f1.setLocation(800 - ((i+x)/2), 500 - (i/2));
            f1.setSize(i+x,i);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
        
    }
}
class fframe extends JFrame implements Runnable{
    Thread t1;
    fframe(){
        super("Electricity Billing System");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        ImageIcon c1 = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("icon/elect.jpg"));
        Image i1 = c1.getImage().getScaledInstance(730, 550,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon(i1);
        
        
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel(i2);
        add(l1);
        t1 = new Thread(this);
        t1.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(7000);
            this.setVisible(false);
            
            Login l = new Login();
            l.setVisible(true);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please Guide me, is it because I haven't downloaded jdbc or something else?

Comment: Do you have any class with a `main` method?

Comment: @iota you can see in the fist screenshot all the classes are right there on the left side and there is no class named 'main' https://github.com/kunaltyagi9/Electricity-Billing-System heres the git link please help

Comment: I'm asking if there is any class with a `main` method. The screenshot does not answer that.

Comment: @iota yess sorry if that sounded rude. i didn't mean to. there is no file names `main` in the whole project

Comment: If there is `main` method in any of the classes, then there is no way to run it.

Comment: @iota is the main class compulsory for a project to run can it not be replaced it with another word?

Comment: @iota when I saw its tutorial it was all working fine

Answer (score 0):

First create your main method in the main class then, to specify the class with the main method: left click on the name of your project, properties, Run, and there specify the main class with the main method.  In your capture: try, Import java.sql.Connection;

Comment: I have updated the question please do check

Comment: Have you already added the Mysql Connector.jar to the Library of your project?   https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/